# Instead of error, why doesn't compiler promote the two literals to type long?

Tags: c#

The following two statements will cause a compiler overflow error ( reason being that constant expressions are by default checked for overflow):

```
int i=(int)(int.MaxValue+100); // error
long l=(long)(int.MaxValue+100); // error
```

But if compiler is able to figure out that adding the two values causes an overflow, why doesn't it then promote both `int.MaxValue` and `100` to `long` and only then try to add them together? As far as I can tell, that shouldn't be a problem since according to the following quote, the integer literal can also be of type `long`:

> When an integer literal has no suffix,
>   its type is the first of these types
>   in which its value can be represented:
>   int, uint, long, ulong.

thanx

Comment: You mean the 100? According to that rule it will always be `int` (unless you add a suffix) as that's the first one that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer, I would imagine, is because it hasn't been designed to. Whenever MS adds features to the C# compiler (or when *anyone* adds features to *anything*), there has to be a cost-benefit analysis. People have to want the feature, and the cost of implementing the feature (in terms of time coding and testing and the opportunity cost of some *other* feature that could be implemented) must be outweighed by the potential benefit that the feature provides to the developer.

In your case, the way to get the compiler to do what you want is simple, obvious, and clear. If they add:

> Infer the type of a numeric expression consisting only of constants and literals to be the minimal type that can contain the resulting value

That means that they now have more code paths to check and more unit tests to write. Changing expected behavior also means that there is probably someone who relies on this documented fact whose code will now be invalid because the inferences could be different.

Answer (score 10):

The literal `100` can be represented as an `int`, which is the first of those four types in that order, so it's made an `int`.

`int.MaxValue` is **not a literal**. It is a public constant field of type `int`.

So, the addition operation is `int + int`, which results in an `int`, which then overflows for this case.

To turn the literal `100` into a `long` so you perform long integer addition, suffix it with `L`:

```
long l = int.MaxValue + 100L;
```

Answer (score 7):

The rules are:

- int + int is int, not long
- the default for arithmetic on constants is "checked"; the default for arithmetic on non-constants is "unchecked"
- 100 and int.MaxValue are constants

Therefore the correct behaviour according to the specification is to do overflow checking at compile time and give an error.

If instead you said:

```
int x = 100;
int y = int.MaxValue;
long z = x + y;
```

then the right behaviour is to do an unchecked addition of two integers, wrap around on overflow, and then convert the resulting integer to long.

If what you want is long arithmetic then you have to say so.  Convert one of the operands to long.

Comment: I assume you're part of the c# development team? Anyways, I was asking more why such a design decision was made rather than how the compiler handles this

Comment: @user702769: I am. The design principles are straightforward. (1) C# is a statically typed language, (2) the vast majority of integer arithmetic comes nowhere near the boundary of the domain, and (3) the language is designed to identify patterns that are likely to be errors or ambiguities and inform the developer of them, rather than attempting to choose for the developer and making a surprising wrong choice.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is all in the sequence. If you read your code, it does: Take an int variable with value MAX, and add 100 to it. This is true in both cases, and this is the code that will be executed before anything else will happen.

If you want to make it work. do

```
long l = ((long)int.MaxValue)+100;
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not the compiler's place to promote types based on the result of run-time expressions.

Both `int.MaxValue` and `100` are integers. I would find the potential for problems if the compiler change the type based on the result of an expression.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what do you expect? You are saying `int.MaxValue+100` which goes over the maximum value allowed for an `integer`! To make it work for the `long`, do this:

```
((long)(int.MaxValue)) + 100;
```

Don't assume the compiler will promote the value to `long` automatically. That would be even stranger.